# Instantiate class in component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, class

> Currently have this

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { RsForm } from './rs-form-model/rs-form.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'rs-form',
  templateUrl: './rs-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rs-form.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class RsFormComponent {

  @Input() form;

  constructor(){}


  ngOnInit(){
    this.form = new RsForm(this.form);
  }
```

> @Input form arrives as a json.

I would like to build a new instance of a class and hand off to this.form.

Is there a way to hand the JSON off to the component constructor so that the DI creates the instance **WITH** the JSON data? as in...

```
constructor(private form: RsForm){
  this.form // would already have the JSON data attached as well as 
  // RsForm class functions.
```

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. But yes, in general, your example of passing it in to the constructor function is valid. Have you tried that and it's not working? What, specifically, are you having an issue with?

Comment: I have tried, I can pass in RsForm and get an instance of it to use. However, I can't give it any data before it is instantiated. I can give it data after and make a function that appends the JSON properties to the class, but that should not be the way to construct a class on the fly. Also, the this.form is undefined at that time in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this,

```
// import 'RsForm' type here

export class RsFormClass {
  form; // if you know what 'type' it is, specify it
  // and other properties...

  constructor(form: RsForm) { // don't forget to import the RsForm interface type in the import section at the top
    this.form = form;
  }
}
```

In your component,

```
// after all the necessary imports including the one for 'RsFormClass'

export class RsFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() form;

  constructor(){}


  ngOnInit(){
    this.form = new RsFormClass(this.form);
  }
}
```